# FireFox invalid date in momentjs

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

Okay so I'm getting my timestamps from my mysql database which is something like
**2015-10-19 14:34:11** and I'm loading it into momentjs like this.

```
var date= new Date(array[data].time)
moment(date).fromNow()
```

but it doesnt work.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle so we can see more code and edit it?

Comment: Please post complete method. Only with this two lines is almost impossible to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `array[data].time` is actually as you described, a *string* such as `"2015-10-19 14:34:11", then you should just do one of the following:

This will interpret the input in the local time zone of the user:

```
moment(array[data].time).fromNow()
```

This will interpret the input in UTC:

```
moment.utc(array[data].time).fromNow()
```

If you are doing things correctly, you most likely want the second one.

The reason your code behaves differently is because Firefox doesn't like that particular format in the `Date` constructor.  Since you're using moment, there's no need to use the `Date` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

moment.js allows strings to be in nonstandard format, but for cross browser consistency, you should convert it to ISO 8601 format on the server side.

your date should look like this `2015-10-19T14:34:11`

> Warning: Browser support for parsing strings is inconsistent. Because there is no specification on which formats should be supported, what works in some browsers will not work in other browsers.

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/